# Spring Data JOOQ with oracle databese

Tags: java, spring-data, jooq

I have comercial project with oracle database. My question is that can I use Spring Data JOOQ for free in my comercial project?

I have found information on JOOQ page that they not support oracle in free edition. Support means that i can't use or they not help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**Open Source Licensing**](https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing) of **JOOQ** and also [**Database Dialect Support**](https://www.jooq.org/download/)
You can not use `Spring Data JOOQ` without have license on it. Because it is not supported in free edition and you have to switch to Commercial editions of `JOOQ`.